# Android camera frame processing using OpenGL

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-camera

I am trying to apply face detection on camera preview frames. I am using OpenGL and OpenCV to process these camera frames at run-time.

```
@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDrawFrame tex=" + mTextureId);
        }

        mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
        mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);

        // TODO: need to implement
        //JniCppManager.processFrame();

        drawFrame(mTextureId, mSTMatrix);
}
```

I am trying to implement a c++ implementation of processFrame(). How can I get a Mat object in c++ from transformation matrix? Could anyone provide me some pointers to the solution.

Comment: The value from `getTransformMatrix()` is a 4x4 matrix represented as a 16-element linear array in column-major order. The OpenCV `Mat` class can certainly represent that, but it's not clear whether you're attempting to get the (usually trivial) transformation matrix or the pixel data itself.

Comment: Thanks Fadden for your response. My eventual goal is to overlay a static image based on the the image recognition. e.g. overlay a mustache on a specific landmark. I think for that I would need pixel data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pipeline is currently:

- Camera (produces frame)
- SurfaceTexture (receives frame, converts to GLES "external" texture)
- [missing stuff]
- Array of RGB bytes passed to C++

What you need to do for [missing stuff] is render the pixels to an off-screen pbuffer and read them back with `glReadPixels()`.  You can do this from code written in Java or native; for the former you'd want to read them into a "direct" ByteBuffer so you can easily access the pixels from native code.  The EGL context used by GLES is held in thread-local storage, so the native code running on the GLSurfaceView render thread will be able to access it.

An example of this can be found in the bigflake [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest), which differs primarily in that it's grabbing frames from a video rather than a Camera.

For API 19+, if you can process frames in YV12 or NV21 rather than RGB, you can feed the Camera to an [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) and get access to the data without having to copy/convert it.

Comment: Thanks Fadden, you answer is super helpful!